# How to implement a generic mapping function?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I want to implement this function:

```
function myMapper(data, mapping) { }
```

With the input being:

```
data = { hello : 'hi' , embedded : { prop1 : 'hiiiii' } };

mapping = { hello : 'HELLO', 'embedded.prop1' : 'embedded.propOne' };
```

The output would be:

```
res = myMapper(data, mapping);

res is { HELLO : 'hi' , embedded : { propOne : 'hiiiii' } };
```

To make it clear:

1. Mapping of simple properties: hello -> HELLO
2. Mapping of nested properties, with dot as separator: embedded.prop1 -> embedded.propOne
3. Old properties are removed (hello and embedded.prop1)
4. This must be a generic function, accepting any complex mapping
5. Not necessary to support renaming of containers: embedded.prop1 -> EMBEDDED.prop1 is **not** needed.
6. The values of the properties stay obviously the same
7. If a property specified in the mapping is not found, it it set to null
8. Bonus points for a reverseMapper which, given the same mapping, does the reverse operation

Comment: I can't imagine the use for such a function. It's trying to do way too many things at once, and would probably give you unexpected results more often than correct results. Regardless, this is pretty off-topic for Stack Overflow. You've just posted a *long* list of requirements and asked us to do your work for you.

Comment: So... are you asking people to implement this for you? Are you asking whether it's a good idea or not? Are you asking for people to review and see if these requirements have any issues?

Comment: This would be a nice entrylevel kata for http://www.codewars.com

Comment: @ajp15243: I am asking for suggestions on how to implement this. @apsk: no idea how to move questions to another forum. @meagar: the use case is implementing a generic `normalizeHash` for a `RestSerializer` in ember-data (which is basically doing what this myMapper is doing, with a custom per-model mapping). I do not share your opinion that this is too complex (although probably it can be splitted in smaller steps): it is *just* mapping properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite trivial, actually:

```
function myMapper(data, mapping, reverse) {
    var res = {};
    for (var n in mapping) {
        var from = (reverse ? mapping[n] : n).split("."),
            to =   (reverse ? n : mapping[n]).split(".");
        for (var o=res, p=data, i=0; i<from.length-1; i++) {
            o = o[to[i]] || (o[to[i]] = {});
            p = p && p[from[i]];
        }
        o[to[i]] = p && p[from[i]] || null;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting, I'll check that now.

Comment: Works fine. Small bug in the inner for loop (p is already defined). And I forgot to mention: properties not specified in the mapping *should be kept as-is*. I'll try to add that now ..

Comment: Yeah, you should've specified that… A `for (n in data) if (!(n in res || n in mapping)) res[n] = data[n];` before the `return` should do it (though not working in reverse case).

Answer (score 1):

This is a general outline you could use. But before diving in, try to solve it yourself, if it is an assignment.

```
function myMapper(data, mapping) { 
     var key, mkey, ret = {};
     for (key in data) {
        mkey = mapping[key];
        //check if there is a direct mapping
        if (mkey !== undefined) {
           ret[mkey] = data[key];  
        } else if (/* check for dot in mkey */) {
            //use similar construct as above but parse mkey
            ret = // assign to the new key
        } else if ... etc.


     }
     return ret;
}
```

Comment: Not an assignment, just a problem in my app with little time to solve. Thanks, but the solution by @Bergi looks simpler (and does dot-splitting and reverse!)